# when nginx+gunicorn, nginx's user=nginx can not access gunicorn's sock file, 403 occured

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I ran into nginx 403 error when using inverse proxy to gunicorn unix sock.

And then I did some tests on [user] setting of nginx.

Firstly, my gunicorn user and group setting are both "ec2-user", and then I run gunicorn command by root user. So the user of gunicorn master process is root and the user of gunicorn worker process is ec2-user. It is OK.

I did 3 tests on nginx [user] setting in nginx.conf file. The result are as follows:

1, nginx worker user=root, every thing is ok.

2, nginx worker user=ec2-user, every thing is ok.

3, nginx worker user=nginx, 403 error occured

gunicorn sock file's property is as follows:

srwxrwxrwx  1 ec2-user ec2-user    0 Augest  22 11:40 gunicorn.sock

On my understanding, gunicorn.sock is almost 777, why nginx worker user=nginx can not access gunicorn.sock?
If I do not want to change default nginx user=nginx setting, Do I have any other method?

Comment: Does the nginx user exist on the system?

Comment: I use 'cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd' to show all the user on the system. The result is that nginx user does exist. But when I type 'su nginx', it shows 'This account is currently not available.'